# Proguard output different obfuscation result from gradle plugin 2.1.2 to 2.3.3

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, proguard, obfuscation

I used for a long time Android Studio 2.1 with gradle plugin `com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2`.

The release build was configured with my custom proguard file and a personal dictionary (containing java keyword as return double, float, etc etc). Using deobfuscator, the folder tree resulted correctly obfuscated.

Now I'm using Android Studio 2.3 with Gradle plugin 2.3.3, with the same code, same proguard file, and the same dictionary, but, after deobfuscation, packages, methods, and classes name remain the same, only variables are obfuscated. Here the different output as PNG images:

[correct_obfuscation](http://res.cloudinary.com/boneatostatic/image/upload/v1500194559/public/correct_obfuscation.png)

[wrong_obfuscation](http://res.cloudinary.com/boneatostatic/image/upload/v1500194559/public/wrong_obfuscation.png)

Where is the matter?

Comment: show me file proguard

Comment: -printconfiguration
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses
-verbose
-dontoptimize
-dontpreverify
-adaptresourcefilenames **.xsd,**.wsdl,**.xml,**.properties,**.gif,**.jpg,**.png
-flattenpackagehierarchy
-obfuscationdictionary proguard_dictionary.txt
-packageobfuscationdictionary proguard_dictionary.txt
-classobfuscationdictionary proguard_dictionary.txt
-dontwarn android.support.**
-dontwarn com.facebook.**
-dontwarn com.squareup.**
-dontwarn org.junit.**
-dontwarn android.test.**
-dontwarn com.github.siyamed.**

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got the solution. The new Proguard version (5.2.1 ) merged my proguard-rules.pro with other exploded-aar proguard files. Now i'm looking for a solution to force proguard using only my proguard-rules.pro, ignoring others aar's proguard.txt files.

Comment: Do you know where to find the merged progard rules?